bluetooth connecting and disconnecting without playing in ubuntu
I had Ubuntu 20.04 on my lenovo thingpad T-480 and I had Bluetooth issues. It connects and disconnects with breaking sound when it plays. After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04, hoping that the issue was going to be solved, nothing changed. Is their a hardware problem in my pc or something. I tested my earbuds with a different Ubuntu machine and they work perfectly. Bluetooth service is running perfectly in my pc. Below is the status of my Bluetooth service running. Pleas help.
tarus@tarus:~$ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-06-24 10:10:41 EAT; 17min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 6462 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18817)
     Memory: 1.1M (peak: 1.8M)
        CPU: 132ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─6462 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jun 24 10:28:25 tarus bluetoothd[6462]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_1
Jun 24 10:28:25 tarus bluetoothd[6462]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_0
Jun 24 10:28:25 tarus bluetoothd[6462]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_1
Jun 24 10:28:25 tarus bluetoothd[6462]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_0
Jun 24 10:28:25 tarus bluetoothd[6462]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
Jun 24 10:28:25 tarus bluetoothd[6462]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream_duplex
Jun 24 10:28:25 tarus bluetoothd[6462]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05
Jun 24 10:28:25 tarus bluetoothd[6462]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05
Jun 24 10:28:25 tarus bluetoothd[6462]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05_duplex
Jun 24 10:28:25 tarus bluetoothd[6462]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex



I wonder if you're using a wifi at the same time when using Bluetooth? If that's so then maybe the problem is because Bluetooth and WiFi share the same 2.4Ghz. I also had the same problem, and I simply changed my wifi to the 5Ghz freq.
It may also be caused by the power management of your wireless card that's automatically turned on. Try to check the output of
mokutil --sb-state && rfkill list all && iwconfig

If it says Power Management:on in the result, then you need to turn it off by using this command.
rfkill unblock bluetooth && sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

Make sure to reboot your device after that.
